# Want to avoid move app to sdcard

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, sd-card

I am programming for Windows Phone 8.1. I use something and I want to avoid move app to SDCard.
If I can't do that, how to detect if an app is moved to SDCard?
If app moved to SDCard, then my app do something.
Thanks.

Comment: As for checking if it's installed on SD - obtain `StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;` and check its *Path* - if the starting letter is different than `C:` - it's installed on SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in the Application manifest to prevent installing this app to SD card. By default it is unchecked.